# How to whitelist installer package during kiosk mode/ lock task mode?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kiosk-mode

I have created an kiosk application it has update functionality for other application within the device but the installer package is blocked. How to whitelist installer package?

I have tried whitelisting this installer package but it is not working. Maybe I'm missing an additional application to whitelist.

```
...//My other whitelisted apps
private static String INSTALLER_PACKAGE = "com.google.android.packageInstaller";
private static String[] APP_PACKAGES = { ..., INSTALLER_PACKAGE};
...
dpm.setLockTaskPackages(cn, active ? APP_PACKAGES : new String[]{});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag on the `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` intent it will generally tell you "Unpinning is not allowed" when trying to invoke the *PackageInstaller* to update.

For instance, in this example (AppCenter)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
intent.setData(fileUri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // <-- giving me grief
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

I have found through my investigations that HockeyApp, Microsoft AppCenter and TestFairy is setting this flag, so I was unable to use their out-of-the-box *in-app* update solution when pinned (task locked). I'm also running `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for what it's worth.

I was however able to change HockeyApp's library to my liking. This was my initial inquiry https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Android/issues/368

Comment: I consider this to be acceptably close to an answer. However, starting it with a question is risky. This might be mistaken for something which should be a comment. I recommend to change this into a conditional answer. Phrase e.g. like "If the problem is that ... then the solution is to ...". This subtly avoids being mistaken for a clarification question, simply by not using a "?". This way of phrasing a conditional answer is an appropriate tool for users below 50 rep. ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead )